# Regex: replace space only if followed by any character else trim

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying, to match and then replace spaces between words.

https://regex101.com/r/edlsbU/1/

Tried: `([a-z].)(\s+)`
But, doesn't work properly.

Tried: `\w+\s\w.*`

Tried: `\w+(\s)(?=\w)` <-- with condition.

[image]

**EDIT:** `^\s*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.-])([a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.\s-]{3,})(?<=\S)[ \s]*$`

But, doesn't trim.

**Expected:**

- **viva** followed by a white space, trim it away.
- **viva la** followed by a white space and a new character, replace white space with **+**.

*I was trying to prepare text for search engine parameter, and realized that when you do a search query: ?q=, you do pass words as: ?q=word+word+word. So, I want to try to write a REGEX that would check if a word has a blank white space and was followed by another word, if it wasn't followed by another word, the blank space would be trimmed. But, if it was followed by another word after blank white space, then a + would be added between the words.*

Comment: It seems much cleaner to do this in two passes - trim first with `s/^\s+|\s+$//gm` and then replace the remaining spaces with `s/\b\s\b/_whatever_replacement_/gm` than try to cram it all in one regex. Where are you even running this? There are might be better options than regex to do this.

Comment: @VLAZ, what would be a better way?

Comment: Doing two replacements, as I described. You cannot even have two different replacement values for a single regex. You use two *much simpler* regular expressions then. Otherwise, you have to make a very complex one that tries to handle many different cases. And I don't really see the value of that. If you're doing this in a programming language (as opposed to, e.g., text editor), then you can utilise string handling functionality to make it even simpler.

Comment: I am doing this in Reactjs.

Comment: What regular expression flavor / language are you using?

Comment: so `str.trim().replace(/\s/g, "+")`? Isn't this *much* simpler?

Comment: @VLAZ, your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @Shawn, I going to use this in Reactjs, JavaScript.

Comment: @AlbinM please add the tag of the language/tool you are using to the question.

Comment: @AlbinM What do you mean? [Seems to work here](https://jsbin.com/derosapili/edit?js,console)

Comment: To be sure what you mean, please define the "word". What kind of chars can your "word" consist of? Please do not use "works/doesn't work" in the problem description, explain what exactly happens and what you expect.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'd expand that and ask for sample representative inputs with sample outputs because it's extremely unclear to me what should happen. All I see is multiple things that OP claims don't work but none of these explain what *should* work and *how* should it work.

Comment: "*trying to prepare text for search engine parameter*" With the additional background, I am even less sure why you want to use a regex. [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) already exists, so you can do `qs = new URLSearchParams(); qs.set("q", str.trim())`. And you can even directly add it to a URL: `url = new URL("http://google.com"); url.searchParams.set("q", str.trim());` [Demo](https://jsbin.com/wopozolere/1/edit?js,console). This is DESIGNED to handle query string correctly. Why reinvent the wheel using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the whitespace chars between word characters and remove all other whitespace chars, you can use a capturing group to see what matched, and use a callback for the replacement.

```
(?<=\w)\s+(?=\w)|(\s+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GU3U2M/1)

```js
let regex = /(?<=\w)\s+(?=\w)|(\s+)/g
let result = [
  "viva",
  "Viva la via"
].map(s => s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => g1 ? '' : `+`))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why one would want to use this over `.trim()`. You have to use code *anyway*, so making a more complex regex in order to use more code for a replacement seems illogical.

Comment: @VLAZ I think the OP wants to `replace spaces between words`. Using `str.trim().replace(/\s/g, "+")` will replace all whitespace chars with a `+`

Comment: I fail to see the difference. After you trim, you *only* have whitespaces between words. If it has to be literally between words (so `foo bar " baz` turns into `foo+bar " baz`), I still don't see the reason *not* to use `.trim()`.  Only you'd replace the pattern `/\b\s\b/` (maybe stick a `+` after the space)  - spaces between word boundaries. [See here](https://jsbin.com/xesayuduta/1/edit?js,console). Still doesn't seem necessary to make a complex regex with a capturing group and then use a replacer function to handle it. It's still complexity for the sake of adding more complexity.

Comment: @VLAZ It is not exactly the same, see the difference in results when using other characters as well https://jsbin.com/citewunugu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: And is this matching OP's requirement? Because to be honest, I don't even know what OP is asking for. It asks for "any character" but then checks for word characters. The input specified is *extremely* simple and doesn't go into details of anything other than words. I never got clarification why OP claims trimming and replacing spaces doesn't work. Yes, we can try making up any amount of inputs that match or don't match a given regex but it's up to the OP to actually clarify *what* the requirement is in the first place.